# Location of config file

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a text file. It has configuration information.  This file should be kept outside so that at anytime the contents of this file can be changed.  While running, the contents should be read from it. I am using netbeans, i tried using the ClassLoader, after i build, the dist folder is not having config_text.txt file.  Is there a way of doing it, like we do to add library files (jar) in netbeans?

Comment: How did you build your project? Do you use maven or ant?

Comment: Netbeans uses ant by default i think

Answer (score 1):

How do you read? If the file is in your project root directory (where eg. build.xml is) you can access it like `File f = new File("my file.txt");` - but NB wont move it do ist folder.

Btw. building won't add any files but libs and your jar to dist folder. Maybe you can try to change the ant script. Take a look at `build.xml` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the file into the "src" folder in your NetBeans project directory then it should be automatically placed in the same relative position in the dist folder and any jar you build. It does for me anyway, I'm running Windows 7x64 and NetBeans 7.1.2 e.g. Placing a file in:

> *NetBeansProjects\PROJECT_NAME\src\PACKAGE_NAME\config_text.txt

Should automatically put the file here:

> *\NetBeansProjects\PROJECT_NAME\build\classes\PACKAGE_NAME\config_text.txt

You could then access it using a getResource() method.

EDIT:

Could it be that your running a "Clean and Build" rather than just "Build"? The first will get rid of everything in the "dist" folder and re-generate the contents, the second will just re-create your Jar and leave the other files (e.g. config_text.txt) where they are.

Comment: You are right, but we distribute the application using dist folder right?  The dist folder does not contain config_text.txt

Comment: @FirmView It is, but it's packaged inside the Jar file. Do you need it to be in there outside of the Jar?

Comment: yeah, so the users can change the contents of the config file and run the application

Comment: @FirmView Ah, do you mean you put it in there, build your application, then it's gone?

Comment: When i build only jar files with readme.txt files remains in dist folder.  No trace of config.txt file

Comment: @FirmView Have you seen my EDIT? It sounds like your cleaning the file before you build

Comment: Yeah, i saw.  I only did build.  The result is same. No luck

Comment: @FirmView I just tried it on my system and "Build" left it where it was meant to be but "Clean and Build" got rid of it. I'm not sure why yours isn't working... :s Could be a preference to always clean before build somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ConfigHandler {

    private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE = "/home/myConfigFile.properties";
    private static final Properties PROPERTIES = new Properties();

    static {
        loadPropertyFile(PROPERTIES_FILE);
    }

    private static void loadPropertyFile(final String path) {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(path);
            PROPERTIES.load(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load property file", e);
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void reLoadPropertyFile() throws IOException {
        loadPropertyFile(PROPERTIES_FILE);
    }

    public static String getProperty(String key) {
        return PROPERTIES.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

To read configuration values anywhere in your code:

```
String somePropertyValue = ConfigHandler.getProperty("someProperty");
```

To reload the config file:
 `ConfigHandler.reLoadPropertyFile();`

Answer (score 0):

I often use the `user.home` property to create configuration files. In my case, I check to see if the file exists in the `user.home` directory. If it does not, then I export a copy from my application, or write default properties to the file. You might want to try that approach. Using the `user.home` directory makes it consistent across platforms too.